# watermark or header in excel file

Tags: python, excel, header, watermark

I create a excel file from a dataframe:

```
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ΜΟΝΑΔΙΚΕΣ_ΠΡΟΣΛΗΨΕΙΣ.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')    
#uniq_pros.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
#writer.save()
```

how can add a watermark in every page of excel file?

or
a header with logo text and image in every first row of pages (or 25lines?)

with python

Comment: For that, ExcelWriter should support those features. Check its API reference to check if it supports them and if it does, check for the methods to use for achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to add a watermark in Excel (as [suggested](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-watermark-in-excel-a372182a-d733-484e-825c-18ddf3edf009) by Microsoft) is to add an image to the header. Here is one way to do it via Pandas and XlsxWriter:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Set a worksheet header with image.
worksheet.set_header('&C&[Picture]',
                     {'image_center': 'watermark.png'})


# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

See also [Example: Adding Headers and Footers to Worksheets](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_headers_footers.html) in the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: I cant see watermark...
I use Libereoffice....Is this problem for i can see watermark?

Comment: It looks like Libreoffice doesn't support Excel's header images